# Image.network throw error even after defining errorBuilder in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, image, networking

I am facing some issues with loading images from URLs in Flutter. Here is my code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
      child: Center(
        child: Image.network(
          'https://www.example.com/no-image.jpg', // this image doesn't exist
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
            return Container(
              color: Colors.amber,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text(
                'Whoops!',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
```

I am using `Image.network` to receive images from a given URL but as the URL does not exist the widget throws a 404 exception, even though the `errorBuilder` parameter is defined. It is not only for 404 exceptions but any network connection errors.

Source of exception (flutter file: *`.../_network_image_io.dart`*):

```
Future<ui.Codec> _loadAsync(
    NetworkImage key,
    StreamController<ImageChunkEvent> chunkEvents,
    image_provider.DecoderCallback decode,
  ) async {
    try {
      assert(key == this);

      final Uri resolved = Uri.base.resolve(key.url);

      final HttpClientRequest request = await _httpClient.getUrl(resolved);

      headers?.forEach((String name, String value) {
        request.headers.add(name, value);
      });
      final HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
      if (response.statusCode != HttpStatus.ok) {
        // The network may be only temporarily unavailable, or the file will be
        // added on the server later. Avoid having future calls to resolve
        // fail to check the network again.
        await response.drain<List<int>>(<int>[]);
        throw image_provider.NetworkImageLoadException(
            statusCode: response.statusCode, uri: resolved);
      }

      final Uint8List bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(
        response,
        onBytesReceived: (int cumulative, int? total) {
          chunkEvents.add(ImageChunkEvent(
            cumulativeBytesLoaded: cumulative,
            expectedTotalBytes: total,
          ));
        },
      );
      if (bytes.lengthInBytes == 0)
        throw Exception('NetworkImage is an empty file: $resolved');

      return decode(bytes);
    } catch (e) {
      // Depending on where the exception was thrown, the image cache may not
      // have had a chance to track the key in the cache at all.
      // Schedule a microtask to give the cache a chance to add the key.
      scheduleMicrotask(() {
        PaintingBinding.instance!.imageCache!.evict(key);
      });
      print(e);
      rethrow; // <<<<<<<< Exception throw here: NetworkImageLoadException (HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, https://www.example.com/no-image.jpg)
    } finally {
      chunkEvents.close();
    }
  }
```

I am wondering if it is a bug or I've made a mistake.

Comment: its not throwing error to me.

Comment: Well, that is wired @DipakPrajapati

Comment: The image URL works fine for me, can you please share the exception along with the question?

Comment: I've found out it was just a debug exception and can get ignored, so my problem has been solved. Thanks for your comment @ibhavikmakwana

Comment: if i try to run on vscode. it's error as you facing. but if i ran on android studio errorBuilder can handle it. i think bug occur with IDE.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct with the implementation. So the thing is, NetworkImage tries to load the image and fails to load it. And hence, the `_loadAsync()` method `rethrows` the exception. Now, as you have provided `errorBuilder`, the framework uses that widget to show when an exception occurs. Hence, you are getting an exception that is rethrown from the framework but is handled as you have provided `errorBuilder`. Now, if you remove the `errorBuilder` you will get the exception logged in debug console, as well as the user, will be able to see that red exception screen if in debug mode and grey screen in release mode.

So, you are correct with the implementation as well as your doubt, but you missed the exact explanation of `errorBuilder`.

I hope this made your doubt clear!

Comment: This answer doesn't help at all. It just goes step by step of what's happening, but it doesn't make it an answer this way. OP has a problem that `errorBuilder` doesn't get invoked.